# Uneven behavior in different system calls hooking

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, hook, kernel-module

I am working on a project in which i have hooked the system open call. When a user attempts to open a file i want sys_open to block the action if the current task (pid or tgid that "black listed" ) has potential to leak the file out of the host.

Any ways, the hooking itself worked fine on **sys_read** and **sys_write** (I have some **printk** inside the fake function as an indicator).

but, when i try the hooking on the sys_open function, nothing is printed out - means that the override not succeeded. 
I printed out the address of the sys call before and after the override so this might not be the issue.

I am confused about what can cause that uneven behavior when hooking different functions.

will be glad for some input here.
thanks !

## dmesg output examples:

#### when hooked write -

> ...
>
> [ 2989.500485] in my write ...
>
> [ 2989.500585] in my write ...

#### when hooked open, noting printed, but here some "debug" output -

> [  890.709696] address found       00000000103d42f6
>
> [  890.709697]   Address before -  0000000006d29c3a
>
> [  890.709698]   Address after  -  00000000a5117c6a
>
> [  948.533339] BYE !!!

using lubuntu vm (kernel v 4.15.0.20).

here is the source code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>             // Macros used to mark up functions e.g., __init __exit
#include <linux/module.h>           
#include <linux/kernel.h>           
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <asm/page.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#include <linux/set_memory.h>
#include <linux/cred.h>
#include <linux/user.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");                                     
MODULE_AUTHOR("ABC"); 
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");



asmlinkage long (*original_call)( char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode);    // for read or  write:  (unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
asmlinkage long my_sys_READ(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
asmlinkage long my_sys_WRITE(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
asmlinkage long my_sys_OPEN( char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode);

unsigned long* find_sys_call_table(void);
void set_page_rw( unsigned long addr);
void set_page_ro( unsigned long addr);
const struct cred *_cred = NULL ; 
struct user_struct *user =NULL ;
unsigned long* sys_call_table = NULL;


void set_page_rw(unsigned long addr)
{

    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(addr, &level);
    if (pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW) pte->pte |= _PAGE_RW;
}

void set_page_ro( unsigned long addr)
{

    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(addr, &level);
    pte->pte = pte->pte &~_PAGE_RW;
}

/*
asmlinkage long my_sys_READ(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count)
{
    //_cred = current_cred();
    user =  get_current_user();
    if( (int)(*user).uid.val == uid )
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT"in my read ... hacked !");    
        return original_call(fd,  buf, count);
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT"in my read ... hacked !");
    return original_call(fd,  buf, count);
}


asmlinkage long my_sys_WRITE(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count)
{
    //_cred = current_cred();
    user =  get_current_user();
    if( (int)(*user).uid.val == uid )
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT"in my write ... hacked !");   
        return original_call(fd,  buf, count);
    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT"in my write ... hacked !");
    return original_call(fd,  buf, count);
}
*/

asmlinkage long my_sys_OPEN( char __user *filename, int flags, umode_t mode)
{

    printk(KERN_ALERT"in my open ... hacked !");
    return original_call(filename, flags, mode);

}

unsigned long* find_sys_call_table(void)  
{
    return   (unsigned long *)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");

}


int init_module()
{

    printk(KERN_ALERT "I'm dangerous. I hope you did a ");
    printk(KERN_ALERT "sync before you insmod'ed me.\n");

    sys_call_table = find_sys_call_table();
    printk(KERN_INFO"address found %p \n",sys_call_table);
    original_call = (void *)sys_call_table[__NR_open];
    set_page_rw((unsigned long)sys_call_table);

    printk(KERN_INFO"  Address before -  %p", (void *)sys_call_table[__NR_open]);
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (unsigned long)my_sys_OPEN;
    printk(KERN_INFO"  Address after -  %p", (void *)sys_call_table[__NR_open]);
    return 0;
}
/*
* Cleanup − unregister the appropriate file from /proc
*/
void cleanup_module()
{
    /*
    * Return the system call back to normal

    */

    if (sys_call_table[__NR_open] != (unsigned long)my_sys_OPEN) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Somebody else also played with the ");
        printk(KERN_ALERT "open system call\n");

    }
    printk(KERN_ALERT "BYE !!!\n");

    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (unsigned long)original_call;
}
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use? What's your glibc version?

Comment: Hm, I cannot see a reason why this shouldn't work. How do you exactly test it?

Comment: The proper way to do this is not to behave like a virus, but to write a [LSM](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/LSM.txt).

Comment: I am using ubuntu lite 18.04 (kernel v 4.15.0.20) ,glibc version 2.27. To test that the hooking part alone works fine i actually print inside my sys_open warper function to dmesg. ** the strange ** part is that when i hooked other sys_calls, it has  printed out whenever the sys_call occurred - which is a lot of curse...

Comment: Can you run `strace` on your use space program that you use for testing to see which system call it calls ?(e.g. it might call openat() instead of open())

Answer (score 4):

Your Ubuntu version is based on glibc 2.27.

glibc version 2.26 [switched to implementing `open` with `openat`](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=b41152d716ee9c5ba34495a54e64ea2b732139b5):

```
commit b41152d716ee9c5ba34495a54e64ea2b732139b5
Author: Adhemerval Zanella <adhemerval.zanella@linaro.org>
Date:   Fri Nov 11 15:00:03 2016 -0200

    Consolidate Linux open implementation

    This patch consolidates the open Linux syscall implementation on
    sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open{64}.c.  The changes are:

      1. Remove open{64} from auto-generation syscalls.list.
      2. Add a new open{64}.c implementation.  For architectures that
         define __OFF_T_MATCHES_OFF64_T the default open64 will create
         alias to required open symbols.
      3. Use __NR_openat as default syscall for open{64}.
```

You will have to hook `openat` in addition to `open` as a result.

Note that the Linux kernel provides a proper interface for this, in the form of the [`fanotify` interface](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html).  If you use that, you will not have to worry about such details.

Comment: many thanks, i would vote for you if i could. 
But still- I would like to know , for next time, how did you find the solution?
 I mean do you work in that area of content so that you are more or less updated?or what are the other tools that available to me for next time ? in general of curse :)

Comment: `strace` and, for complicated cases, [Systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) are are useful tools for system call tracing. For hooking file I/O independent of file systems, `fanotify` is the recommended interface.